# Clarification about GroupCombine with respect to partial results

Tags: apache-flink

Flink's documentation for `GroupCombine` states:

> Note: The GroupCombine on a Grouped DataSet is performed in memory with a greedy strategy which may not process all data at once but in multiple steps. It is also performed on the individual partitions without a data exchange like in a GroupReduce transformation. This may lead to partial results.

With the following remark for full (non-grouped) `DataSet`s:

> The GroupCombine on a full DataSet works similar to the GroupCombine on a grouped DataSet. The data is partitioned on all nodes and then combined in a greedy fashion (i.e. only data fitting into memory is combined at once).

Does this mean that if my dataset consists of, for example:

```
1
2
3
```

and I want to generate all pairwise combinations

```
(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)
```

I cannot implement this in a general way with a `GroupCombine` transformation because it doesn't guarantee that the whole group will fit in a given partition's memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GroupCombine` is a non-deterministic operation in Flink. It is typically used to perform partial compuations (like aggregations) and is followed by a deterministic operation like `GroupReduce` that consumes the partial results. `GroupCombine` is typically used to reduce the cost of the deterministic operation by performing less-expensive local, in-memory computations.

If you need compute deterministic results on groups of records, you should use `GroupReduce`.

Comment: So just to be clear, my interpretation is correct and I shouldn't use `GroupCombine` for the aforementioned example?

Comment: Yes. With `GroupCombine` you'd (most probably) not get the full result.